# How to intercept web url from chrome and add headers to the request?

Tags: java, jsp, rest, http, single-page-application

given:  my chrome browser hits the following url that renders a single page application web view (index.jsp).

url: http://server/dostuff?stuff=123

however, what I want to do is somehow intercept that GET request and tack on a header to it (i.e. X-HIDE-MAIN-FOOTER). if this header is present the code simply hides the footer.

doing so would allow me to see the output per chrome (and verify the footer is hidden.

I have tried sending a raw GET request through postman and other api-rest test tools with that header included in the GET request but the payload comes back with a lot of javascript tags (the same ones as a regular request so I can't tell if the header is hidden or not) and won't render the page in preview mode per postman nor can I save the file locally as .html to see what gets rendered.

any ideas here how to achieve something like this?

Comment: Try using modifying header https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en

Comment: There is one extension in chrome, Redirector. http://code.google.com/p/chrome-redirector/downloads/detail?name=Redirector-2.2.22.5.crx May be this would help you..

Comment: @AllahbakshAsadullah that worked great!  you should add that as the answer and I can check mark it as such!  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked very well

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en

credit to @Allahbaksh Asadullah